# how to import your own github forked library into android studio

Tags: github, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I found a nice open library on GitHub, I imported it into my Android Studio project using Gradle dependencies, but then I realized I need to make little modifications on it.

So I forked the library on my GitHub, done the modifications and asked for a pull request, but I can't wait until they approve and merge my modifications with the original code.

Is there a way to use dependencies to import my forked library (in my Github) into my Android Studio project, rather than the original library?

Comment: I have the same problem, but all i can think of is `Import as Module` way , since you have it in your disk. I know this isnt the solution your looking for but I think this is the only way(I think) as of now.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is actually a really easy way to do this nowadays: [jitpack.io](http://jitpack.io)

All you need to do is.

1. add in your root `build.gradle` *at the end* of allprojects repositories:

   allprojects {
   repositories {
   ...
   maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
   }
   }
2. Add the dependency in your app build.gradle:

   dependencies {
   implementation 'com.github.User:Repo:Tag'
   }

If you don't have any releases/tags, you can also just do `com.github.User:Repo:branchname-SNAPSHOT` to build from the latest commit on that branch.

Comment: this is actually the cleanest way to import a lib. thanks for sharing!

Comment: Can jitpack.io also be used to install a forked plugin instead of a library? I would like to install https://github.com/hierynomus/license-gradle-plugin/pull/184 in my project, but this approach doesn't work or at least it's not clear to me how to apply to a plugin ...

Comment: When we move from `jCenter` to `mavenCentral` we should use this advice. For example, `implementation 'com.github.savvisingh:DateRangePicker:master'`, `implementation 'com.github.RedMadRobot:input-mask-android:6.0.0'`.

Comment: Strong +1 for the `branchname-SNAPSHOT` thing

Comment: branchname-SNAPSHOT work for me, thank you

Comment: how about mono repo
https://github.com/androidx/androidx/tree/androidx-main/compose/material3/material3

Answer (score 16):

I know that this is an old post, but for someone with similar problem, if you simply want a way to change a lib and use it in your project, you can download the lib code, change it and import into your project as a module:

1. Open your project in Android Studio
2. Download the library (using Git, or a zip archive to unzip)
3. Go to File >  New > Import Module and import the library as a module
4. Right-click your app in project view and select "Open Module Settings"
5. Click the "Dependencies" tab and then the '+' button
6. Select "Module Dependency"
7. Select the imported module
8. Open your build.gradle file and check that the module is listed under dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

This is how you should do it:

- Fork the repo.
- make changes and commit them
- edit the push urls to your github forked repository.
- make a release/tag
- head over to jitpack.io
- generate a url to add to your gradle file

Answer (score 1):

- Fork and library from Github you want improve
- Open Android Studio > Load Project from Version Control
- Select the project or enter the url (You must be signed to Github version
  control)
- Now you can Commit and Push to Github without any issues.
- Tag the project with new version, Git > Tag > Create tag
- Open the app gradle file and add:

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
    group='com.github.yourgithubusername'
```

and open the root gradle file and add:

```
   classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1'
```

- Go to Android Studio Terminal And type:
  ./gradlew install
- Now Commit and Push to github
- Go to Jitpack (SignIn with Github on 1st Use)
- Select the library
- Copy the Gradle plugin code after selecting the tag:

implementation 'com.github.username:repo:tag'

Comment: With version `2.1` I had not have to add apply plugin and the group.