# Android Studio 3.1 : Could not find org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

Yesterday, I updated Android Studio to 3.1 and I'm getting this error :

```
 Could not find org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824.
Searched in the following locations:
    https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
    https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
Required by:
    project :library > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:26.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:26.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:26.0.1 > com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:26.0.1
```

This is my project's gradle file :

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
//        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'

        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is my gradle-wrapper-properties's distdistributionUrl:

```
distdistributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

Comment: Error says it isn't searching `jcenter`

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try to replace all occurences of mavenCentral() with jcenter() in your gradle builds

Comment: I just replace  the root gradle's allprojects node. It's work for me !Thank you !

Comment: Could not find org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom

Comment: Perfect! It worked for me. I'm just curious, how do you know about it?

Comment: This is no longer valid as jcenter is sunsetting May 1st 2021

Comment: @ElliotM, yes. See my answer below for Maven.

Answer (score 19):

Because [jCenter will close in May](https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/), you should replace it with Maven. Thanks to [giorgos.nl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1087449/giorgos-nl) now we can add `Trove4j:20160824`. Thanks to [Xavier Rubio Jansana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3286819/xavier-rubio-jansana) we can replace `maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }` with `gradlePluginPortal()`.

In root `build.gradle` write:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        // org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824.
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
```

To add libraries that have not still been moved to `mavenCentral`, use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28749014/how-to-import-your-own-github-forked-library-into-android-studio).

Root `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Then you should search `GitHub` repositories of not resolved libraries. App's `build.gradle` example with two libraries:

```
dependencies {
    // When a library has tags.
    implementation 'com.github.RedMadRobot:input-mask-android:6.0.0'
    // When a library doesn't have tags.
    implementation 'com.github.savvisingh:DateRangePicker:master'
}
```

Now we can launch an application and build apk without errors.

Comment: `http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/` is on Alibaba cloud. If you have concerns about China, you can use instead `https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/` to get `trove4j:trove4j`

Comment: `maven {url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }` can be replaced by the shortcut `gradlePluginPortal()` when using Gradle 6 or newer.

Comment: @XavierRubioJansana, thank you very much! I added your advice.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same mistake ... and for me the following worked:

1. Add `jcenter()` to `repositories {}` of `allprojects`
2. And add `compile 'org.jetbrains.trove4j: trove4j: 20160824'` in the build.gradle app module

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error. I also had **jcentre()** at the appropriate place. But still it was not working.
One thing you can do which worked for me is clear the caches:

**1. Close Android Studio.**

**2. Clear caches in here:**

C:\Users"username"\.android\caches

C:\Users"username"\.gradle\caches

**3. Open Android Studio.**

Also make sure you have the version of the gradle which is newer than the minimum required.